# ListView gets Hang for 2-4 Second on loading data

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

I have a scenario where i update data in list view after every 15 seconds.

The data displays in ListView, which has 18 columns and 10 rows. I have created an ArrayAdapter where i define style and bind data to the view.

The problem is that after each 15 seconds when it hits the server, get JSON, parse it and add it to the List View. In the process, UI gets hangs for 2-4 seconds.

I need to know how can i avoid this delay, I have tried `Handler`, `AsyncTask` but none of this is Helping.

This is what i am doing.

I have added 2 `Tab Layouts`,each has `ListView`

```
tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_gd_players);
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.gd_player_details_view_pager);
tabViewPagerAdapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());


homePlayersFragment = new PlayersFragment();
awayPlayersFragment = new PlayersFragment();

tabViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(awayPlayersFragment, awayTeam);
tabViewPagerAdapter.addFragments(homePlayersFragment, homeTeam);

viewPager.setAdapter(tabViewPagerAdapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**On Each 15 Seconds Interval I do this.**

```
    homePlayersFragment.setData(dataModel, "homeTeam");
    awayPlayersFragment.setData(dataModel, "awayTeam");
```

**In Fragment, I initialize ArrayAdapter**

```
  public void setData(PlayerDataModel dataModel, String fragmentName){
        this.dataModel= dataModel;
        this.fragmentName= fragmentName;

        if(dataModel != null) {

            GDPlayersNameAdapter gdPlayersNameAdapter = new GDPlayersNameAdapter(getActivity(), dataModel, fragmentName);
            lvPlayersName.setAdapter(gdPlayersNameAdapter);

            GDPlayersDetailsAdapter gdPlayersDetailsAdapter = new GDPlayersDetailsAdapter(getActivity(), dataModel, fragmentName);
            lvPlayersDetails.setAdapter(gdPlayersDetailsAdapter);
        }
```

So the `setData()` get called after each 15 seconds.

In Adapter I am passing the data to the columns, If i remove the number of columns from 18 to 1, it stops hanging.

I am unable to understand where the actual problem is.

Kindly guide me the best way to resolve this problem.

Comment: And how 15sec action is triggered ?

Comment: Obviously you are doing long running task on GUI thread. `AsyncTask` should do the trick but most probably you dont know how to use it properly.

Comment: You'll need to add your adapter code, if not more, to allow others to help. It's not clear what your adapters do. Use the traceview tool to get a better view of where cycles are being spent.